# How to make an alias for localhost that has a tld?

Tags: linux, archlinux

I was wondering how I would make an alias for localhost that has a tld.
For example, foo.test wold connect to 127.0.0.1.
I tried just adding a second line to /etc/hosts that also pointed to 127.0.0.1, but that didn't seem to work. Although, I didn't reboot, so that might be why.

The end goal is to have it so that I can test that a request is being sent to a specific subdomain in the Rocket framework for Rust. IE: foo.bar.test instead of baz.bar.test or just bar.test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for /etc/hosts says:

```
IP CANONICAL ALIAS ...
```

```
127.0.0.1 foo.test localhost
```

Should be good

But is the host really handling traffic from this IP address ?

Alternatively, the interface specific line can include the aliases

```
10.0.0.1 foo.bar.test foo
10.0.0.2 baz.bar.test baz
```

Comment: Worked, although I also had to set an alias for IPv6:
```
::1 foo.test localhost
```